# Svelte: how to use native web APIs

Tags: svelte

In a Svelte app, how can we access native web APIs, such as the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API), to, for example, use the [window.showOpenFilePicker()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/showOpenFilePicker) method?

Comment: Are you encountering an error of some sort when you try and use native web apis? It shouldn't require anything special, for example here's a button using `window.alert`: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-bardeen-kuhp6?file=/Button.svelte

Comment: @tiberriver256, thanks for the example, yes I'm getting an error: 'Property 'showOpenFilePicker' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis''. It's a TypeScript issue, so I suspect that since your window.alert() method works,  window.showOpenFilePicker() will work too, I may need to extend the TS window object for Svelte (if that's possible), or tell TS to ignore the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get Typescript support for the new WICG File System Access APIs you'll need to make the following two changes:

1. Install the `@types/wicg-file-system-access` npm package into your dev dependencies (i.e., for npm `npm install --save-dev @types/wicg-file-system-access`).
2. Add the types to your tsconfig.json file

```json
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["@types/wicg-file-system-access"]
  }
  ...
}
```